# How could I do an interceptor for EntityManager.class

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I want to audit insertions, updates, deletions, etc using entitymanager. For this, how could I do an interceptor for EntityManager.class that will work with EJB???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to add an interceptor for that, simply use JPA's [callback methods](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg014.htm) and/or [entity listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg015.htm).

With the first approach, you add to an entity methods declared with one of these annotations: `@PrePersist`, `@PostPersist`, `@PreUpdate`, `@PostUpdate`, `@PreRemove`, `@PostRemove`, or `@PostLoad`. The names are self-explanatory, meaning that for each event (pre-persist, post-persist, etc.) the annotated method gets called.

The second approach is similar, but the methods are implemented in one or more separate classes, which in turn are added to the entity using the `@EntityListeners` annotation.

The second approach is more flexible, but either way you can intercept persistence operation right before/after they occur and perform the operations you need.

Comment: I know it, but for instance, if I need to audit a @PreUpdate, when this callback method is executed, it seems that JPA has already attached my entity updated. In fact, to audit I need the last values of my entity.

Comment: A `@PreUpdate` is guaranteed to be invoked at some point _before_ the database update. For storing the previous value(s), in `@PostLoad` save the current value(s) in another attribute(s) of the same entity; the "old" value(s) will be there when `@PreUpdate` executes, and the "new" values will be in the usual attributes of the entity at that point.

Comment: But on @PreUpdate method, how could I get the old value?

Comment: As I said above: in `@PostLoad` you save the current values in a different set of attributes. When you reach `@PreUpdate` those attributes will hold the "old" values, whereas the "new" values will be found on the normal attributes.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't solve my problem. I would like an interceptor for EntityManager class. Is it possible?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could add an `entity-listener` element in the `persistence-unit-defaults` of the `orm.xml` file, (see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html#d0e3102)). Other than that, and short of writing your own `EntityManager`, no, you can not have an interceptor for the `EntityManager` class.