# In javaee6 is there a way to know which fields have update on an entity?

Tags: hibernate, persistence, jpa-2.0

I'm currently working on an entity logging mechanism. And I have added an entity listener with PreUpdate, etc. Is it possible to know which fields have been updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think an `org.hibernate.Interceptor` fits your need.
 Just extends `EmptyInterceptor` and works with `onFlushDirty()` and others methods.
I hope can help.

EDIT:
With annotation you can get a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294439/how-could-i-do-an-interceptor-for-entitymanager-class): you can work with entity lifecycle and store/compare properties on your needs

Comment: Hi, I've seen this approach but I think I cannot use this as annotation? Session session = factory.openSession( new MyInterceptor() ); I don't use SessionFactory in my app.

Comment: I found a new solution here in SO, but is a bit weird (IMO). Take a look and check if can help! Good work!

Comment: Hi, I've seen that link before but I don't want to save the attributes in another set. I think I just have to create a custom gson serializer.